# Custom control property from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I will make an industrial HMI application with OPC. I want to display variables of PLC with radio buttons. But I want to choose the plc varaible on radiobutton properties area. There is a class which includes all PLC's variables. I want to choose different variable for each radiobutton from this class. And if variable is true it will be checked.

To do this I want to make custom radio button on c# and add custom propeties to it.

I can make a custom radio button but I could not relate it's property area with another class varibales. When I clicked property area It should display all variables of a class

How can I do that?

```
 public partial class My_RadioButton : RadioButton
{

    private VarsFromPLC _FrPLC;

    [Description("Displaying PLC Variables"),
     Category("Appearance"),
     TypeConverter(typeof(VarsFromPLC)),
     Browsable(true)]
    public VarsFromPLC FrPLC
    {
        get { return _FrPLC; }
    }


    public My_RadioButton()
    {
        _FrPLC = new VarsFromPLC();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}

public class VarsFromPLC
    {
        public bool bTry1 { get; }
        public bool bTry2 { get; }
        public bool bTry3 { get; }
        public bool bTry4 { get; }
        public bool bTry5 { get; }
        public bool bTry6 { get; }
        public bool bTry7 { get; }
        public bool bTry8 { get; }
        public bool bTry9 { get; }
        public bool bTry10 { get; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "I can make a custom radio button"...."a dropdown list should be open " dropdown in radiobutton??? Could you please explain what do you want

Comment: I will make an industrial HMI application with OPC. I want to display variables of PLC with radio buttons. But I want to choose the plc varaible on radiobutton properties area. there is a class which includes all PLC's variables. I want to choose different variable for each radiobutton from this class. And if variable is true it will be checked. Sorry for nonclear question.

Comment: Ok, no problem :) Also please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

Comment: Could you maybe illustrate how you want it to look and what it should do?
I am very curious as to how you would visualize the solution.

Comment: Is it right that you want to show properties in designer via dropdown?

Comment: @Sebi absolutely right. But properties options will be element of a class. I will select within them. And if its value is true radio button will be checked.

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet maybe this will help you (write above your Property): [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]

Comment: No it did not worked.

Comment: *When I clicked property area It should display all variables of a class.* What do you mean, what's property area?

Comment: I'm not sure but do you need [such UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9kyF.gif)?

Comment: Simply create an `Enum` and define the property of type your enum. Also you can use a `TypeConverter` or a `UITypeEditor`. But the first option is really easy. But I can't guess what would be the usage of such property in a radio button!

Comment: I need booleans because I will communicate with opc server and will display booleans values with this custom radiobutton

Comment: But it doesn't describe about having such property in radio buttons. The usage of a group of `RadioButton` controls is exactly like a `ComboBox`. The goal is showing the selected option among available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read the answer about adding such drop-down to property grid, consider these notes:

- The usage of a group of `RadioButton` controls is like the usage of `ComboBox` to show/modify selected option among available options.
- If you want to show value of those properties, it seems you are looking for data-binding.
- If just one of those properties can be set to `true`, you can create a group of `RadioButton` controls and bind each control to the corresponding property of that class. This way the radio buttons can be used to show/modify those properties.
  **Note:** In this case it seems it's better to have an enum containing all options and just a single property of type of that enum in the class.
- If more than properties can have `true` values, you can use a group of `CheckBox` controls and bind them to corresponding property of the class.

---

Anyway if you want to show such drop-down in property grid, you can use either of these options:

- You can create an `Enum` and define your property of that enum type. This way a drop-down will be shown in property grid for your property. (**The most simple option**)
- You can register a custom `TypeConverter` for your property and overriding `GetStandardValuesSupported` provide some standard values for the property to show in drop-down. To see an example, take a look at: [Type Converters That Provide a List of Standard Values to a Properties Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx#Anchor_1)
- You can register a `UITypeEditor` for the property. As an example take a look at [Walkthrough: Implementing a UI Type Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx)

Comment: It list all options but not a direct answer. My question is clear but answer is so general. Anyway. I will try. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the feedback :) The most simple option is using enum to provide standard options in property grid. But surely it's better to read the answer carefully :)